# Laravel queued event is giving error: Data too long for column 'queue'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

Facing an weird problem in Laravel queue. May be I am doing something wrong with event and queue.

#### Background

I have a an Event, that event is being broadcasted to pusher, so, we have the `broadcastWith()` method. Just to keep informed, this `broadcastWith()` method sometimes may be a big big array. But it's not as big as the limit of pusher broadcast.

I it's trying to save the event's data in `jobs` table. We are getting this error when that event triggered:

### Illuminate\Database\QueryException

`` SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'queue' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `jobs` (`queue`, `attempts`, `reserved_at`, `available_at`, `created_at`, `payload`) values ([{"id":246,"visit_id":337,"doctor_id":109,"patient_id":1,"enqueued_at":"2020-06-16 14:16:39","dequeued_at":null,"created_at":"2020-06-16 14:16:39","updated_at":"2020-06-16 14:16:39","patient":{"id":1,"user_id":8,"person_id":7,"created_at":"2020-05-18 15:56:31","
.......<a very big chunk of json> ``

It's trying to save the data in `queue` columns of `jobs`. It's laravel's generated table and the type of the `queue` column is `varchar(255)`. I got stuck! Why Laravel itself is trying to that long json data in `queue` table when it's capacity is only 255? I am sure changing the data type and increasing the queue column's capacity is not the solution here. So,

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: You need to change the column type to `LONGTEXT` from `VARCHAR`.

Comment: No, as I said in the question already. I am sure this is not the solution. Laravel generate the table by itself and Laravel insert the value itself too. May be I am using Laravel is some unexpected way.

Answer (score 0):

jobs table structure must be `id` `queue` `payload` `attempts` `reserved_at` `available_at` & `created_at`.

In your insert query, **payload** column is at the end. Simply fix the ordering and you are good to go.

Comment: That's my issue. I am not doing it manually myself, nobody who use Laravel insert these value manually. Why would Laravel do this in wrong order while this table is generated by itself? I don't have even controll over it, I am just triggering the broadcasting event and it's returning this.